# Network issue between VMWare guest and windows host

Tags: twisted, vmware, buildbot

I have a windows 7 host, on which I am also running a windows 7 virtual machine, essentially I'm trying to setup buildbot, the host runs the build master while the vmware virtual machine will run the build worker. The virtual machine network adapter is configured to **host only**. The virtual machine It has an ip address of 192.168.1.12, while the host has an ip address of 192.168.1.92. Both addresses are static IPs there's no DHCP involved
I can ping the host from the virtual machine, and I can ping the virtual machine from the host.
But when I try to get both the build master(host) and the build worker(vm) to communicate, nothing seems to happen. Looking at the twisted log in the vm I can see error messages along the lines of

> "TCP connection failed to connect to host on ip 192.168.1.92:8999"

Note the buildbot.tac on the build worker(vm) has the ip address of the host (192.168.1.92) and the port on which to connect 8999

I have tried **netstat -ano** on both the host and the vm and I cannot see any connection between the two.

I have tried turning off the firewall inside the virtual machine, just in case, but no success there either

Any suggestions.

Comment: Use ``nmap`` (or something similar for Windows) to see if the ip/port is open.  On the host machine, run: ``nmap 192.168.1.92/24|grep 8999``.

Comment: I have two **guesses**:

 * your Buildbot master listens (if at all) to a different port
 * there's a firewall involved (allowing pings, but TCP/IP connections)

Your `netstat -ano` should show if Buildbot listens for a connection on the specified port.